# React JS - If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, axios

I am using React for my app, I am fetching data from an API at http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers/supplier/list

Here is the data structure that I am getting in the Google Chrome console:

```
0:{
    id: 4
    supplierFirstname: "Tom"
    supplierLastName: "ABC"
    supplierTitle: "TomTheSupplier"
    accountNumber: 1122234444
    address: "111 ADrive, 1234 ST."
    companyName: "TheTom Company & Associates"
    email: "tomtomjayjay@email.com"
    hourlyRate: 29
    phoneNumber: 123456789
    otherPhoneNumber: 1023456789
    paymentTerms: "Credit"
    notes: "Some Supplier"
    createdAt: null
    typeOfGoods: "Supplies"
    website: "www.abc_123.com"
    products: [{…}]
    components: 
        [
            0: {id: 5, name: "AComponent", unit: null, quantity: 0, componentCost: 0, …}
        ]
    
}
```

Here is my code:

```
class SupplierData {  
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        supplier: [
            {
                id: 0,
                supplierTitle: "Supplier Title",
                supplierFirstName: "First Name",
                supplierLastName: "Last Name",
                accountNumber: 1122234444,
                address: "",
                companyName: "",
                email: "tomtomjayjay@email.com",
                hourlyRate: 29,
                phoneNumber: 123456789
                otherPhoneNumber: 1023456789
                paymentTerms: "Credit"
                notes: "Some Supplier"
                createdAt: null
                typeOfGoods: "Supplies"
                website: "www.abc_123.com"
                products: [{…}]
                components: 
                  [
                   0: {id: 5, name: "AComponent", unit: null, quantity: 0, 
        componentCost: 0, …}
        ]
            },
        ],
        errorMessage: [],
    };
}


 ListAllSuppliers = async () =>{
    return await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers/supplier/list`)
        .then((response) =>{
            let apiResults = response.data;
            this.setState({supplier: apiResults});
            
        }).catch((error) =>{
            this.setState({errorMessage: this.state.errorMessage.push(error)});
        });
  }

 

 TableRow = ({id, supplierTitle, supplierFirstName, supplierLastName}) => {

        return (
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span className="fw-normal">
                        {id}
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span className="fw-normal">
                    {supplierTitle}
                  </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span className="fw-normal">
                    {supplierFirstName}
                  </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span className="fw-normal">
                    {supplierLastName}
                  </span>
                </td>
          </tr>
          );
        };


 render(){

         return(
            <table>
              <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th className="border-bottom">#ID</th>                          
                        <th className="border-bottom">Title</th>
                        <th className="border-bottom">FirstName</th>
                        <th className="border-bottom">LastName</th>
                        
                    </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  {this.state.supplier.map((t) => this.TableRow(t))}
               </tbody>
             </table>
          );
     }
```

I am getting the following error, here is what it states:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, productComponents, 
quantity, productCost, productPrice, createdAt, status}). If you meant to render a collection of 
children, use an array instead.
in span (at SupplierData.js:158)
in td (at SupplierData.js:157)
in tr (at SupplierData.js:78)
in tbody (at SupplierData.js:259)
```

why is it pointing out such error                          .

**My Question:**

What is a possible fix to the above error ?

Comment: Are you sure that apiResults has the same structure as this.state.supplier ?

Comment: @Sowam I have updated the question with the data structure I am getting from apiResults.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the `tr` tag:

```
return (
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span className="fw-normal">
                {id}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span className="fw-normal">
                {supplierTitle}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span className="fw-normal">
                {supplierFirstName}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span className="fw-normal">
                {supplierLastName}
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
);
```